# Is it safe to use drywall anchors for a heavy bookshelf between two studs?

Tags: drywall, shelving, drywall-anchor

I want to put a bookshelf (heavy load) in a small alcove where I have access to threw studs, two 11" apart (left side) and the other two 28" apart (right side).

I would like to mount standards to this and will need something in the center to keep the wood from bowing.

Can I mount a standard on either end and then use some drywall anchors for a third standard in the middle?

This small bits of tape indicate where I marked off screws to help find the studs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes this will be fine if you use the right type of anchor, you need toggle bolts of some sort.  For example a 3/16" toggle bolt in 1/2" drywall can support 70# of load.  If you have two or three of these on the middle shelf bracket, it will be more than adequate.

I'd recommend snaptoggles, eztoggles, or other variant that holds the toggle in the wall without the bolt - these are much easier to use.

[image: snaptoggle]

When you select your shelf brackets, you'll want something that you screw fast to the wall; you don't want something with the "keyhole" type mounting holes, where you basically hang the shelf brackets off the screws.

Comment: I was planning to use E-Z Ancor Twist-N-Lock (75 lb) anchors along the center standard. I've had good luck with these elsewhere for hanging various things.

Comment: @zhro - toggles are much stronger - the 70 pound rating I mention is with a 4x safety factor.

Comment: I agree that they would be stronger but this would be a vertical sheering force across several anchors. I think the larger in-wall surface area of the E-Z Ancor would be superior in this instance.

Comment: I have had great luck with EZ anchors , love them. But you should be careful in between the studs where the duct is.  Pushing or pulling on the sheet metal duct in the center can create a lot of noise when the duct expands and shrinks from heating and cooling.+

Comment: The duct goes straight through the wall to the other side. It doesn't tunnel vertically through that wall. The ducts are all outside of the walls unless they have to pass through to get to another room.